# Typescript error 2322 with React ComponentType and props interface

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm writing a function that expects a React component type as an argument. The component type's interface must extend a specific interface that includes methods our function relies on.

I've included a very minimal/contrived example but it throws the following error:

```
Type '{ foo: number; }' is not assignable to type 'TComponent'.
  '{ foo: number; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'TComponent', but 'TComponent' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Test'.(2322)
```

I thought I understood this issue as I've encountered it before but am not understanding what the solution needs to be.

In reality, I'm applying the exact `props` the component's interface allows except I've replaced `foo` with an internal value. The end result is the *same* but I suppose the error is typescript saying the subtype could have changed what `foo` is?

```
import React, { ComponentType, JSX } from 'react'

interface Test {
  foo: number
  test: string
}

const openWindow = 
  <TComponent extends Test>(Window: ComponentType<TComponent>, props: Omit<TComponent, 'foo'>):
    JSX.Element => <Window foo={123} {...props} /> // errors on Window
```

Comment: Typescript is saying that your component props could change even if you extend Test, to make it work do it like this `<Window {...props as TComponent} foo={123}  />`

Comment: Ok thanks, I guess that does fix it. Unfortunately in my real code the function type is entirely separate from the function definition so I don't have access to `TComponent` without redefining some of the types